# Spring security access denied exception

Tags: spring-security

I have a web page which is connected to a spring `@component` class.
There is a method that requires roles(by spring  annotation `@Secured('ROLE_USER')`) and it is called with a button.

My problem is when i click the button without having the required role,it causes an error named access denied exception.I want to redirect the page to error a page when this occurs. I tried access-denied-handler on application context but it did not work.

By the way, is `@component` tag enough or should i add something else such as `@controller`?

Answer (score 2):

Just add an error page to your web.xml like this

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>403</error-code>
  <location>/pages/accessDenied.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

If you want to set error page using accessDeniedHandler take a look at this [How to redirect to access-denied-page with spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244238/how-to-redirect-to-access-denied-page-with-spring-security)